# PHP: OOP connection to database use multiple

Tags: php, database, oop, database-connection

I use this code for connect to database

```
class DB {
    private $connect;

    public function connect(){
        if(!$this->connect){
            include "config.php";
            echo "CONNECT";
            $this->connect = mysqli_connect($config['HOST'],$config['USER'],$config['PASS']);
            if($this->connect){
                $select = mysqli_select_db($this->connect,$config['NAME']);
                if(!$select){
                    echo "Not Found Database !";
                    exit();
                }
            } else {
                echo "Not Connect To Database !";
                exit();
            }
        }
        return $this->connect;
    }

    public function query($query) {
        $result = $this->connect()->query($query);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

And use this code for connect and after select from database

```
$db = new DB();
$connect = $db->connect();

$db = new DB();
$way = $db->select("SELECT * FROM `setting`");
```

After run this code , print on page :

```
CONNECTCONNECT
```

Why not work `if(!$this->connect){` in line `3` and connect twice ?

Comment: Because  `new DB` creates a _new_ instance. Since your connection variable isn't static, the variable is not shared between instances.

Comment: @JonStirling, thank you, my code is normal ?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by normal. It's certainly a pattern that we see an awful lot, not that that makes it a good thing, but it depends on implementation.

Comment: @JonStirling,i want use good solution, how can i ?

Comment: To be honest, my suggestion is not to do this yourself but to use existing libraries. If you use a framework, they usually have a recommended / default abstraction layer they use. There are too many variables to be more specific. Or you could just continue as is and learn along the way. Up to you really :P.

Comment: You can use the singleton pattern to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of the singleton pattern to provide this

```
class DB {
     private $connect;
     protected static $instance;

     public static function getInstance() {
          if (null === self::$instance) {
               self::$instance = new self;
          }
          return self::$instance;
     }

     protected function __clone() {}
     protected function __construct() {}

     public function connect(){
          if(!$this->connect){
               include "config.php";
               echo "CONNECT";
               $this->connect = mysqli_connect($config['HOST'],$config['USER'],$config['PASS']);
               if($this->connect){
                    $select = mysqli_select_db($this->connect,$config['NAME']);
                    if(!$select){
                         echo "Not Found Database !";
                         exit();
                    }
               } else {
                    echo "Not Connect To Database !";
                    exit();
               }
          }
          return $this->connect;
     }

     public function query($query) {
          $result = $this->connect()->query($query);
          return $result;
     }
}
```

Then use the class instance anywhere in your app

```
$db = DB::getInstance();
$connect = $db->connect();

$db = DB::getInstance();
$way = $db->select("SELECT * FROM `setting`");
```

Comment: `s/pattern/anti-pattern/` ;)